# Data won't show up in DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql

I have following problem: 
I want to fill a datagridview with data from a database, but the data just won´t show up

My code:

```
using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(s_connectionstring)
{
    command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.Raumnr, " +
                            "LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.Raumbezeichnung, " +
                            "LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.`Raumbereich Nutzer` " +
                            "FROM LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume " +
                            "WHERE(((LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.tabelle_projekte_idTABELLE_Projekte) = " + s_whichID + "))" +
                            "ORDER BY LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.Raumnr;";
    adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds);
    dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
    label1.Text ="change Text"
}
```

I don´t get any errors, but the datagridview does not show any data although when I debug, I can see, that it contains values

**Solution:** I moved this code to another part in my code, now it works, dont ask me, what the problem was

```
private void elementeabgleichToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(s_connectionstring)
        {
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.Raumnr, " +
                                    "LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.Raumbezeichnung, " +
                                    "LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.`Raumbereich Nutzer` " +
                                    "FROM LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume " +
                                    "WHERE(((LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.tabelle_projekte_idTABELLE_Projekte) = " + s_whichID + "))" +
                                    "ORDER BY LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.Raumnr;";
            adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds);
            dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
            label1.Text ="change Text"
        }
    }
```

Comment: is your query returning values?

Comment: 1)did you run this query outside?
2)if possible show data

Comment: just updated my code - yea, i ran it in mySQL workbench ant there it works

Comment: " ' " + s_whichID+ " ' " -may be this?

Comment: no I tried it hard coded, does not change

Comment: it is in a method, not a button click, could this be the reason why it wont show up, also i can´t change the text of a label

Comment: You should rebuild the grid after assigning the datasource

Comment: 'LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.tabelle_projekte_idTABELLE_Projekte'-

is tabelle_projekte_idTABELLE_Projekte your column name?

Comment: @Curious how to i rebuild

Comment: There must be a method. Like dataGridView1.Rebuild(); or dataGridView1.Refresh();

Comment: use-ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: @ksl123 dont mind the sql statement, it also does not work when I use SELECT * FROM LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume

Comment: @ClemensSteinbauer-does any error comes up?
use-SELECT * FROM  tabelle_räume

Comment: no, I think the SQL statement is ok

Comment: the label also does not change

Comment: Add a breakpoint on  dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable.DefaultView;. Check if the dataTable has any values. Running the query in workbench does not mean everything goes according to plan in here. if you got 0 values in table it means you get nothing from db. Else the problem is somewhere else

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan, it has values, but it does not show up in the form

Comment: are you doing this before inizialization of your view?

Comment: @DanieleSartori no after, the gridview is already existing

Comment: I have the feeling other lines of code are cauzing the issue. Make a new project. Add a grid and plain this code see if it executes. I don't see any reason why the line would not execute.

Comment: I'm not an expert of winforms, but it seems you are missing a BindingSource?

Comment: UPDATE:
I moved it to another part of my code, not it works, dont ask me why ...

Comment: Maybe you can post from where you moved the code so in future people with same problems can have a fix.

Answer (score 0):

check this lines the error should be in SQL syntax.

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.Raumnr, " +
                            "LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.Raumbezeichnung, " +
                            "LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.`Raumbereich Nutzer` " +
                            "FROM LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume " +
                            "WHERE(((LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.tabelle_projekte_idTABELLE_Projekte) = " + s_whichID + "))" +
                            "ORDER BY LIMET_RB.tabelle_räume.Raumnr;";
```